# Having an issue retrieving list from database using Ecplise

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I'm currently working on a coupon project. While working on my facade class, I encounter an issue getting a list of coupons that customer has purchased by entering his ID from a table with foreign keys.

The method I was using:

```
@Override
public List<Coupon> getPurchasedCoupons(int customerID) throws SQLException {
    {
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();

        ArrayList<Coupon> customerCoupon = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Long> customerCouponID = new ArrayList<>();
        Statement stmt = null;

        long coupID = 0;
        stmt = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `couponsystem`.`customers_vs_coupons` WHERE (`CUSTOMER_ID` = '?')");

        while ((resultSet != null) && (resultSet.next())) {
            coupID = resultSet.getLong("COUPON_ID");

            customerCouponID.add(coupID);
        }

        Iterator<Long> myIterator = customerCouponID.iterator();

        while (myIterator.hasNext()) {
            Long couponID = myIterator.next();

            resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(
                    "SELECT * FROM `couponsystem`.`customers_vs_coupons` where COUPON_ID = " + couponID);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                Coupon coupon = new Coupon(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getInt(2),
                        Category.categoryFor(resultSet.getInt(3)), resultSet.getString(4), resultSet.getString(5),
                        resultSet.getDate(6), resultSet.getDate(7), resultSet.getInt(8), resultSet.getDouble(9),
                        resultSet.getString(10));
                customerCoupon.add(coupon);
            }
        }

        ConnectionPool.getInstance().restoreConnection(connection);

        return customerCoupon;
    }

}
```

Coupon class:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Coupon {

    private int id;
    private int companyID;
    private Category category;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private int amount;
    private double price;
    private String image;

    public Coupon(int companyID, Category category, String title, String description, Date startDate, Date endDate,
            int amount, double price, String image) {
        this.companyID = companyID;
        this.category = category;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Coupon(int id, int companyID, Category category, String title, String description, Date startDate,
            Date endDate, int amount, double price, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.companyID = companyID;
        this.category = category;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Coupon() {
        super();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCompanyID(int companyID) {
        this.companyID = companyID;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getCompanyID() {
        return companyID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coupon: ID = " + id + ", Company ID = " + companyID + ", Category = " + category + ", Title = " + title
                + ", Description = " + description + ", Start Date = " + startDate + ", End Date = " + endDate
                + ", Amount = " + amount + ", Price = " + price + ", IMAGE = " + image;
    }

}
```

Calling the method:

```
public List<Coupon> getCustomerCoupons() throws SQLException {

    return coup.getPurchasedCoupons(customerID);

}
```

My SQL table:

Coupon_vs_Customer table contains only 2 rows. which both are foreign keys to other tables.
CustomerID is connected to table of 'CUSTOMERS' while coupon_ID is connected to table 'COUPONS'

```
CustomerID   Coupon_ID
1             1
1             2
1             3
```

As you can see above customer with ID 1 owns 3 coupons, and I'm trying to read them in a list on my eclipse project.

I do not get any exception, however I get returned an empty arraylist. I cannot seem to solve this issue since I am quite new to JDBC.

Comment: `'?'` is literally a string with a question mark, it is not a parameter. And even if it were, you are not using a prepared statement, so you're not populating parameters. Furthermore, your code exhibits the so called N+1 query problem, you should use a single query instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query tries to find customers with id = "?". Maybe this was an attempt to create a prepared statement but then you need a few more steps

```
String query = "SELECT COUPON_ID FROM couponsystem.customers_vs_coupons WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setInt(1, customerID);

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: In my what part of my code should I add this step and should I replace it with my first query?

Comment: Yes this is instead of your first query

Comment: now I get an exception "Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 3 > 2. " like its trying to access a column that does not exist. Thing is. I am trying to to get all coupons from a different table that customer with  I has purchased.

Comment: I guess that is from your second query? Try to rewrite it to use a prepared statement in the same way as the first one and don’t do “SELECT *” but instead list the columns you want to include in the query by name.

Comment: I think the issue is this line 'coupID = resultSet.getInt("COUPON_ID");' this line causes the exception and I have no clue why. I used your method and it gives me the errors with that line.

Comment: I don’t think that is something I can help you with, besides it feels irrelevant to the original question